# Haskell, stack 'ExitFailure1' on build

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack

I got an ExitFailure1 again. Now on Stack when I build a file (used to have this on Cabal, led me to a complete dirty reinstall). I have the feeling it is caused by the '`./stack-work`' permission denied. But where to find this '`./stack-work`'? Looking forward to you professional opinion, rather than me nuking the entire install again.

```
Configuring teststack-0.1.0.0...
.stack-work/dist: createDirectory: permission denied (Permission denied)

--  While building package teststack-0.1.0.0 using:
      /Users/administrator/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-osx/Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_2.2.0.1_ghc-8.4.4 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-2.2.0.1 configure --with-ghc=/Users/administrator/.stack/programs/x86_64-osx/ghc-8.4.4/bin/ghc --with-ghc-pkg=/Users/administrator/.stack/programs/x86_64-osx/ghc-8.4.4/bin/ghc-pkg --user --package-db=clear --package-db=global --package-db=/Users/administrator/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-12.17/8.4.4/pkgdb --package-db=/Users/administrator/Desktop/Haskell/hs_level_0/teststack/.stack-work/install/x86_64-osx/lts-12.17/8.4.4/pkgdb --libdir=/Users/administrator/Desktop/Haskell/hs_level_0/teststack/.stack-work/install/x86_64-osx/lts-12.17/8.4.4/lib --bindir=/Users/administrator/Desktop/Haskell/hs_level_0/teststack/.stack-work/install/x86_64-osx/lts-12.17/8.4.4/bin --datadir=/Users/administrator/Desktop/Haskell/hs_level_0/teststack/.stack-work/install/x86_64-osx/lts-12.17/8.4.4/share --libexecdir=/Users/administrator/Desktop/Haskell/hs_level_0/teststack/.stack-work/install/x86_64-osx/lts-12.17/8.4.4/libexec --sysconfdir=/Users/administrator/Desktop/Haskell/hs_level_0/teststack/.stack-work/install/x86_64-osx/lts-12.17/8.4.4/etc --docdir=/Users/administrator/Desktop/Haskell/hs_level_0/teststack/.stack-work/install/x86_64-osx/lts-12.17/8.4.4/doc/teststack-0.1.0.0 --htmldir=/Users/administrator/Desktop/Haskell/hs_level_0/teststack/.stack-work/install/x86_64-osx/lts-12.17/8.4.4/doc/teststack-0.1.0.0 --haddockdir=/Users/administrator/Desktop/Haskell/hs_level_0/teststack/.stack-work/install/x86_64-osx/lts-12.17/8.4.4/doc/teststack-0.1.0.0 --dependency=base=base-4.11.1.0 --enable-tests --enable-benchmarks
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
MacBook-2:teststack administrator$
```

Comment: Same again with Cabal. Example of installing threepenny-gui:
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
threepenny-gui-0.8.3.0-57EYYliZ1loIOlAOTIgmI2 failed during the building
phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1

Comment: If this is a continuation of a previous question, please edit that question instead of starting a new one.  If this is a new question, what command did you run?  Where is the code of `teststack`, so that we can try to reproduce the behavior?  If it is a permissions issue, what is the output of `ls -al`.  Pay attention to the difference between `./stack-work` and `.stack-work`.  The latter is a hidden directory in your current directory; the initial `.` tells MacOS & Linux to hide a directory.

Comment: What catches my eye here is the "permission denied" bit. In particular, Stack is meant to be ran from your regular user account; you shouldn't be running it as admin or with elevated permissions. (Assuming typical workflows, the same goes for cabal-install.)

Comment: @Duplode, closed the other thread since they're related. Other systems require me to run the entire machine in admin. Should I sandbox the entire Haskell installation? I assumed stack/cabal was just asking for elevated permissions, hence the reason I didn't understand.

Comment: (1) I'm not sure I get what you mean by "sandbox the entire Haskell installation", but in any case running either cabal-install or Stack from your user account requires no special preparation: even if the tools themselves are installed globally (e.g. because you got them from your package manager), they default to installing packages to a suitable place in your user directory. (2) On another note, `.stack-work` is the directory in which Stack puts build artefacts. Stack creates it as a subdirectory of the project you are working on.